# How to find basis using the transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am given a matrix A that represents transformation T:P3 -> P2 with respect to standard basis. Matrix B obtained by row reducing A represents the same transformation with respect to other basis, V and W. I need to find these basis. How should I proceed?

Comment: You appear to be in the same class as the user who asked [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683088/finding-bases-for-a-linear-transformation-of-a-matrix)...

Comment: Oh yes that's true.  Although I didn't want to know the answer explicitly. But thanks a lot! :)